# Spring Boot ошибка: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, spring-boot

Я новичок в spring boot, и перерыл уже кучу статей, не получается подключить к монго, на момент запуска сервер работает, это мой application.properties

```
server.port=9960

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=shop_product
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

и лог об ошибке

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

pom https://gist.github.com/artem-kurilko/c5ea73e33b731cf8f271969552aba474

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Покажите ваш `pom.xml`. Скорее всего у вас нет нужной зависимости(драйвера mongoDB)

Comment: @Chubatiy https://gist.github.com/artem-kurilko/c5ea73e33b731cf8f271969552aba474

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из простых [решений](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44826982/8370915) может быть добавление в файл `application.properties` строчки ниже в том случае, если Вам не нужен [JDBC datasource](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/) :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Также Вы можете дополнить `application.properties` файл [дополнительной информацией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24086178/8370915) в виде строчек:

```
spring.datasource.url = …
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = …
```

[Например](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-data-source-programmatic),

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Добавив при необходимости в POM [зависимость H2 базы данных](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25340415/8370915):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.156</version>
</dependency>
```

Для получения более детальной информации, можете обратиться к официальной документации:

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource
>   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource